# Handheld music player in the 1890s?

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, technology, identification

Perusing [this gallery of candid photos from 1890s Oslo, Norway, by Carl Størmer (1872-1957)](https://www.boredpanda.com/spy-camera-secret-street-photography-carl-stormer-norway/?page_numb=6), again I found such a curious image, yet was unable to verify the existence of any portable music player back then.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_radio#19th_century),

> Over several years starting in 1894 the Italian inventor Guglielmo
>   Marconi built the first complete, commercially successful wireless
>   telegraphy system based on airborne Hertzian waves (radio
>   transmission).

That device looks awfully small, though; could it be a brush? Was brushing your hair in public without a mirror common then?

[image: 1890s lady with a device that looks like a cellphone]

Are these things from [1928 movie *The Circus* by Charlie Chaplin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwy6gSs-ljA) and [1938 Dupont Massachusetts factory footage](http://www.asiantribune.com/node/69881) the same kind of device?

[image: 1938 devices that look like cellphones]

I was only able to find others with the same question: **What are those things?**

Comment: [There were portable music players in the 1890s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_box#History), just not the sort you're thinking of.

Comment: @Mark I have a couple of those, but they are smaller and too loud to hold up to one's ear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [*The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/11/debunking-the-charlie-chaplin-time-travel-video/65486/) they are **hearing aids**, patented in 1924. So was Norway ahead of its time in technology, or behind in fashion? Neither; the 1890s photo most likely depicts an [**ear trumpet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_trumpet):

[image]